# PostgreSQL Function to dynamically reshape and create tables in loop function

Tags: postgresql, function, dynamic-sql

I am pretty fresh to PostgreSQL, so please be kind.

I am pretty sure that my problem is that I am mixing plain and dynamic SQL. I have read the [relevant documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) but I am not experienced enough to see where I have gone wrong (hoping that my issue is not something more fundamental).

Currently the script is failing with a Query execution error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"

I intend to use this function to unpivot >9,000 tables (for analysis purposes); fortunately all tables have the same structure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION all_schemaTables_unpivot(_schemaName text, _tableName text)

RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
    _tbl record;
BEGIN
   FOR _tbl IN
      SELECT 
         quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename) AS fName, 
         quote_ident(tablename) AS tName
      FROM   pg_tables
      WHERE  schemaname = _schemaName
      AND    tablename LIKE _tableName
   LOOP
      EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || _tbl.tName || '_up AS
                 SELECT region_id, key AS sequential_id, value
                 FROM (SELECT row_to_json(t.*) AS line, region_id
                       FROM ' || _tbl.tName || ' AS t) AS r
                 JOIN LATERAL json_each_text(r.line) ON (key <> "region_id")';
   END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are missing spaces at many places while concatenating them with  a variable, for eg `'CREATE TABLE' || _tbl.tableName` or `FROM' || _tbl.tableName`

Comment: indeed what @KaushikNayak says the dynamic SQL in that is unvalid SQL..Valid SQL has spaces between keywords.. `'CREATE TABLE' || _tbl.tName || '_up AS` generates `'CREATE TABLEtablename_up AS` for example

Comment: Thanks @kaushik, I have adjusted those concats but am still getting the same initial error "SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the script to work I just needed to fix two things:

1. I originally did not set appropriate spaces around the query concatenating (thanks @KaushikNayak)
2. I incorrectly set the quoting values around my dynamic variables (see the 'quote_ident(_tbl.newTableName)' addition. People more expert in PostgreSQL than I will surely have a much cleaner approach - but at least it works!

Moral of the story, sometimes the fix is staring you in the face, but you have been staring at the script for too long! Leave it for awhile and the answer becomes clear.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
all_schemaTables_unpivot(_schemaName text, _tableName text)
RETURNS void AS

$BODY$
DECLARE
_tbl record;
BEGIN
FOR _tbl IN
  SELECT 
    quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename) AS fullNamePath,
    quote_ident(tablename) || '_up' AS newTableName
  FROM   pg_tables
  WHERE  schemaname = _schemaName
  AND    tablename LIKE _tableName
LOOP
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE '|| quote_ident(_tbl.newTableName) ||' AS
         SELECT region_id, key AS sequential_id, value
         FROM (SELECT row_to_json(t.*) AS line, region_id
               FROM '|| _tbl.fullNamePath ||' AS t) AS r
         JOIN LATERAL json_each_text(r.line) ON (key <> "region_id");';
END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```